# Intercept Azure AD token generation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, token

We are developing an application with NET Core and a SPA in Angular.

The application incorporates Azure AD to validate if a user exists, but we need to validate some properties in a proprietary database before Azure generates a Token.

If we can not do these validations, Azure will generate a valid Token and the [Authorize] attribute will pass all the requests.

Is there any way to intercept Token generation from Azure AD?

It is true that we can make a security filter that validates each request, but there are too many roundtrips and isn't elegant.

Answer (score 0):

In your single page application, there will be a place where you initiate the AD authentication. In my case, I am using Angular 5 in my SPA and I am using [adal-angular5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular5) for handling the authentication.

There is a method init() available in the library, only by calling it, the authentication starts. I have made the other validations before calling the init() method.

I suggest you to do the same and the APIs which you hit before init() should be open APIs (without authentication)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Arunprabhu But I have no possibility of knowing which user is going to login in Azure from the SPA because we redirect to the Azure window and Azure only returns a token

Comment: Oh you need the user details before the login?

Comment: If you are not exposing the APIs, you can handle it in UI. Make an initial API call after the login for checking the validations. If the call fails, redirect the user to a custom page saying that the application is inaccessible or logout the user.